# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path:

Tags: java, eclipse, web, tomcat, rxtx

We are using RXTX library to communicate from Java web based program to serial port.

But we are getting "`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path:`" error when trying to connect to serial port.

We are using Eclipse and Tomcat (as app server). It's a web based application.

Added [ `-Djava.library.path="C:\directory\rxtx"`] to VM arguments in tomcat run configuration.

File "**rxtxSerial64.dll**" is in "`C:\directory\rxtx`" and "**rxtx-2.2.jar**" is in `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

How can we resolve this error?

Comment: Suggestions like what?

Comment: Like setting 'native Library path' or putting the dll in jdk_home/bin directory etc

Comment: Can suggest your solution that worked for you. Happy to try and see if it solves our error.